# Joining on a combined synthetic primary key instead of multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have table, `winners`:

| Player | Team |
| --- | --- |
| John | Blue |
| Becky | Red |

And I would like to join it to a table, `points`:

| Player | Team | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Blue | 8 |
| John | Red | 3 |
| Becky | Red | 7 |

And I would like to get the points for each winner. I know that I can do so using the following join:

```
SELECT
    W.PLAYER
  , W.TEAM
  , P.POINTS
FROM WINNERS W
INNER JOIN POINTS P
    ON W.PLAYER = P.PLAYER AND W.TEAM = P.TEAM
```

Is there any performance loss if I write the query the following way, which uses a synthetic primary key to avoid joining on multiple fields:

```
WITH WINNERS_NEW AS (SELECT
                         PLAYER || '_' || TEAM AS ID
                       , PLAYER
                       , TEAM
                     )
   , POINTS_NEW AS (SELECT PLAYER || '_' || TEAM AS ID, 
                           POINTS
                    )
SELECT
    WN.PLAYER
  , WN.TEAM
  , PN.POINTS
FROM WINNERS_NEW WN
INNER JOIN POINTS_NEW PN
    ON WN.ID = PN.ID;
```

The impetus behind this question is that in my actual use case, I need to repeatedly join on 7+ fields, and can avoid this by creating a synthetic primary key earlier in the CTE, but I'm not sure if doing so will lead to significant performance losses.

Comment: Nice SO reputation score btw ;)

Comment: _"to avoid joining on multiple fields"_ - what's wrong with having multiple `ON` criteria in a `JOIN` operator?

Comment: `SELECT w.PLAYER, W.TEAM.P.POINTS FROM winners w` <-- I'm not too familiar with Postgres' latest stuff, is `W.TEAM.P.POINTS` a new syntax for navigating joins?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a typo and should be `W.TEAM, P.POINTS`, based on the expected output.

Comment: Short answer is that yes, it can cause significant performance degradation. If there are no indices on these columns, it's probably not an issue, but if these are indexed columns, joining on an expression instead of the fields will prevent those indices from being used, greatly reducing the query planner's options. It is also possible to create an index on that concatenated expression, FWIW. And, as always, you'll want to actually measure this by trying it out on your own dataset to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation and makes sense. Honestly no problem w/ joining on multiple fields, issue on my end was wanting to have as concise code as possible.

Comment: @DJC _"wanting to have as concise code as possible"_ - I get you: SQL is _painfully_ verbose, unfortunately it's the way it is :(

Comment: Your first query is readable and very simple. It is recommended to create indexes only for the `PLAYER` and `TEAM` fields, do not need anything else. But the second query is not recommended. Because indexes will not be used in subqueries. Also, you don't need to complicate the query with additional operations

Comment: Thanks all. @AdamKG if you can comment your answer happy to give it the green check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can cause significant performance degradation.

If there are no indices on these columns, it's probably not an issue, but if these are indexed columns, joining on an expression instead of the fields will prevent those indices from being used, greatly reducing the query planner's options. For what it's worth, it is also possible to [create an index on that concatenated expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html), though it would be unusual in my experience to do so for query-conciseness reasons; supporting things like case-insensitive matching is the more common use case for expression indices.

As always, to get a definitive answer, measure it by trying it out on your own dataset .